# `bash` variable reference doesn't get updated

Tags: bash, shell

How to reference variables correctly within a multi-lined string in the script below?  Assigning `MY_INFO=INFO2` does not produce the desired updated output.

Example script:

```
#!/bin/bash

INFO1="output1"
INFO2="output2"
MY_INFO=INFO1

if [ True ]; then
    INFO="
    Here are the test results
    bbb
    ccc
    aaa
    ${!MY_INFO}
    " 
fi

echo "First:"
echo "$INFO"

MY_INFO=INFO2

echo "Second:"
echo "$INFO"
```

Output:

```
    First:

    Here are the test results
    bbb
    ccc
    aaa
    output1

    Second:

    Here are the test results
    bbb
    ccc
    aaa
    output1
```

Desired output:

```
    First:

    Here are the test results
    bbb
    ccc
    aaa
    output1

    Second:

    Here are the test results
    bbb
    ccc
    aaa
    output2
```

Comment: Using `MY_INFO=$INFO2` or `MY_INFO=INFO2` still returns the same output.

Comment: The code acts exactly as one would expect -- why would you think that changing MY_INFO would affect the value of INFO?  despite the similar names, the variables have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: As an aside, all-caps variable names are used for variables with meaning to the operating system or shell -- names with lowercase characters are reserved for application use; thus, for names in your scripts you don't mean to impact other parts of the system, you should be using them. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that setting a shell variable will overwrite any like-named environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Since `if [ true ]` is the same no `if` at all, we may dispense with the `if ... fi`.

To get [late evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding) of a variable, the potentially dangerous `eval` command works:

```
#!/bin/bash

INFO1="output1"
INFO2="output2"
MY_INFO=INFO1

INFO="
Here are the test results
bbb
ccc
aaa
\${!MY_INFO}
" 

echo "First:"
eval echo \""$INFO"\"

MY_INFO=INFO2

echo "Second:"
eval echo \""$INFO"\"
```

Output:

```
First:

Here are the test results
bbb
ccc
aaa
output1

Second:

Here are the test results
bbb
ccc
aaa
output2
```

Answer (score 1):

your INFO string is not reevaluated again on your second call, you can convert it to a function to accept a variable input, for example...

```
#!/bin/bash

INFO1="output1"
INFO2="output2"

info() { echo "
    Here are the test results
    bbb
    ccc
    aaa
    $1
    ";}

echo "First:"
info "$INFO1"

echo "Second:"
info "$INFO2"
```

or, with variable indirection, still using the function

```
#!/bin/bash

INFO1="output1"
INFO2="output2"

info() { echo "
    Here are the test results
    bbb
    ccc
    aaa
    ${!MYINFO}
    ";}

echo "First:"
MYINFO=INFO1
info

echo "Second:"
MYINFO=INFO2
info
```

Answer (score 1):

In bash 4.3, you can use *namevars* (formerly a ksh feature) to create linkings between variables that behave as you intend here:

```
var1="hello"
declare -n var=var1    ## declare -n makes var a "namevar" pointing to var1
var="goodbye"
echo "$var1"
```

...emits `goodbye` when run.

---

That said, inasmuch as what you're looking for is a *template*, `envsubst` is the appropriate tool for the job -- though it **doesn't** support indirect expansions itself:

```
info_template='Here are the test results
${my_info}'

info_good='Successful test!'
info_bad='Failure!'
result=good
result_var=info_$result

my_info="${!result_var}" envsubst <<<"$info_template"
```

Unlike `eval`, `envsubst` isn't prone to security vulnerabilities. When displaying test output, this is arguably much more of an appropriate priority than making your code a bit slimmer by moving the indirect expansion into the template itself.